# Do you know how to fix this error when Debugging in IIS on Windows 10 Home

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis

I am trying to run a visual studio project locally on Windows 10 Home but get this error:

[image: Screen shot of modal error dialogue]

I suspect I may need to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro - but wanted to know if there is a work around?

TIA

Comment: (I am already running VS as admin)

Comment: There should be an entry in the Application event log about this error.

Comment: Error log:

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.19041.1, time stamp: 0x58c67bf3
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4360.0, time stamp: 0x606e6fc7
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00000000000492dc
Faulting process ID: 0x4960
Faulting application start time: 0x01d76b5deddee45b
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report ID: 8d0b5b15-dc64-4d42-8deb-414ea8a897a7
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: